# Property 'picker' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker

i am trying to make this picker but it says it doesent exits, does anyone know how to help me?

```
Code:
<mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
    <input matStartDate placeholder="From Date">
    <input matEndDate placeholder="To Date">
  </mat-date-range-input>

<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>//error happens here
```

Comment: <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker" #picker></mat-datepicker-toggle>

Comment: i did what you said i got this error: Type 'MatDatepickerToggle<any>' is not assignable to type 'MatDatepickerPanel<MatDatepickerControl<any>, DateRange<any>, any>'.

Comment: What are you trying to do? you want to open data picker but you have no datapicker in html

Comment: what no, the guide im following dont say nothin about datepicker variable

Comment: your html does not have `mat-date-range-picker`,  Read my anwer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working example

```
  <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
    <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date">
    <input matEndDate placeholder="End date">
  </mat-date-range-input>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
```

Comment: Thank you That worked been sitting on the problem for a while now and didn't know how to fix it, so thank you :)

Comment: Great to be of help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your `app.component.ts` doesn't have a `picker` named variable